# Cannot build cordova project after add RevenueCat

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, revenuecat

I have a problem build my project with RevenueCat.
I installed it for Apache Cordova by this manual: https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/cordova 
But now after build it return:

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources
/home/martin/Projects/LearnEnglishWordsV3/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchases/PurchasesPlugin.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        Purchases.getSharedInstance().setUpdatedPurchaserInfoListener(new UpdatedPurchaserInfoListener() {
                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class UpdatedPurchaserInfoListener
  location: class PurchasesPlugin
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/martin/Projects/LearnEnglishWordsV3/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchases/PurchasesPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Do you anybody know what can I to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is fixed after update on version 1.2.2 
Version 1.2.1 was wrong: https://github.com/RevenueCat/cordova-plugin-purchases/pull/54